# app.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined at app.js:1

Tags: angularjs

This is index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="quizApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular JS Quiz App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="quizController">
           {{message}}   
        <script src="src/libs.js"></script>
        <script src="src/scripts.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

This is app.js

```
var quizApp = angular.module('quizApp',[]);
```

when i console  i m getting error as

> app.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined   at app.js:1

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you have in `src/libs.js` I don't think you are importing the Angular code at all;

Add this line to your `<head>` element:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js">
</script>
```

You can see the beginners examples on the angularjs website:

https://angularjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to load angular.min.js/ angular.js before writing `angular.module('quizApp',[]);`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Just load .js file and your error will be removed.